# What is the difference between Mongoose Delete and Express app.delete

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am learning NodeJS and using MongoDB for a database (mongoose to interact). The current course I am doing is only using the mongoose methods to "Delete" and "Update" and using Express to make a "post" request to do it. ie:

```
app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
  //do something
  Item.findByIdAndRemove(item, function(err){
  })
})
```

But if you check the Express basic routing Docs they suggest using:

```
app.delete('/item', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Got a DELETE request at /item')
})
```

I know everything should be RESTful and using a POST request to make a DELETE request could cause problems, but in this case are they both accomplishing the same thing? Sorry if this question is newbie or hard to make sense of, It was just something I had noticed while I was reading an article about REST today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better practice to use `app.delete`, rather than `app.post`, because it reflects the nature of what the endpoint does. It's easier to see you want to DELETE an item in the below code:

```
app.delete("/item", (req, res) => { /* Delete item */ });
```

But a POST request is used to post a new item to the storage - so it's less clear. The only other conventional way is to use a GET request with the method name in the URI (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSKp2StlS6s) for poor RESTful API practices, this one included).

```
app.get("/delete-item", (req, res) => { /* Delete item */ });
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you. Good video

Comment: Thanks @ColtonVanBastelaere, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

POST is used to add data to the database, while DELETE deletes an items from the database. It allows for clearer code and is useful in postman as you can have the same URL but it is a different request so you can have a different response.